# How to achieve this Adobe Xd?

Tags: vector, website-design, shapes, interface-design, adobe-xd

I want to do this in Adobe Xd, can someone please tell me is there any way or any **plugin** to achieve this in adobe xd.

> Note: The current image is from Figma.

[image: Video]

Although I know we can do this by using the **Boolean Groups**.
But it is time-consuming when you are working with more than 100 screens on a page right??

Comment: Do you just want to make this shape... or a chart? I think as far as the shape goes this is probably the quickest way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLxNZIdF2LE&t=55s – But if it's a chart, some kind of chart plugin would likely be better. I mean it is basically a donut chart.

Comment: @Joonas I wanted to make the shape. The video you send it helped thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this. This is a little bit more tricky, a bit of a hack, but it works.

Use the border size, dash and gap settings.

Set a large gap size, then you can adjust as shown below. Clicking and dragging up or down on the fields will change the values.  If the shape isn't in the right orientation you can rotate it.

[image]

Another possibility is to draw a white filled shape with the Pen Tool to cover over the circle. You can add more anchors to adjust the covering patch, and anchors can be selected and deleted if required.

[image]

Yet another possibility would be to use the top shape as a mask

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use figma 
I recently read an article on why figma is better than xd
and this was one of the reason
.
.
https://uxplanet.org/why-you-should-use-figma-instead-of-adobe-xd-as-a-designer-18091d429444

Comment: I cannot choose that is the problem. Because my company is using is adobe xd